# Android ActionBarSherlock does not display custom view with setDisplayShowCustomEnabled

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm working with `ActionBarSherlock` and have an app with several tabs. In one of the tabs I'm trying to display a `SearchView` using `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

Since the search should only appear in one of the tabs, when this tab becomes visible, I'm calling `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);` and when a different tab becomes visible, I'm calling `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);` to hide the search.

This works well on Android 4+ (when the stock ActionBar is used), but does not work on older versions (when the replacement is being used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around, it appears that in the rest of the tabs I'm showing a title. It seems that showing both a title and a custom view does not play well together - for some reason when you do this, both are hidden and you end up seeing nothing.

Fix:

When the search tab is visible:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

and when a different tab is visible:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
```

So the solution was to hide the title accordingly.

This was only required in old Android versions, as it was working without the title part on Android 4+